# Why scrollView won't be infinitive in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uiscrollview, infinite-loop

So here is the code that I used for scroll view to show infinitive (showing image again, again and again) and scroll automatically vertically. The problem is that it will scroll but the images won't repeat and they will be finished and I just see white.

This is the code:

```
import UIKit

class initViewController: UIViewController , UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var scrollViewHeight: CGFloat!
let numPics: Int = 1
var y = CGFloat()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x :0, y:0, width : self.view.frame.width, height : self.view.frame.height)

    let scrollViewWidth: CGFloat = self.scrollView.frame.width
    scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height

    var arrPics = [UIImageView]()

    for i in 0...numPics {

        let iv = UIImageView()
        arrPics.append(iv)
        arrPics[i] = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x : 0,y : scrollViewHeight * CGFloat(i),width : scrollViewWidth, height : scrollViewHeight))

        arrPics[i].image = UIImage(named: "splash.png")

        self.scrollView.addSubview(arrPics[i])

    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(numPics+1))
    let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(initViewController.scrollP), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width : self.scrollView.frame.width, height :self.scrollView.frame.height * scrollViewHeight )
}

@objc func scrollP() {

    y += 15
scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), animated: true)

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is actually only counting from 0 to 1.

```
for i in 0...numPics {
 ...
}
```

At the top you initialize numPics to 1. You are therefore only adding one photo to the scrollView.

```
let numPics: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this isn't making the scroll view really infinite and repeating the initialization of image view. I believed that you only want to create the effect of infinite scrolling.

1) Remove the part that create extremely long scrollView

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width : self.scrollView.frame.width, height :self.scrollView.frame.height * scrollViewHeight )
}
```

2) Duplicate your first image and append it to the end of your image array.

3) Change your scrollP function to something like:

```
@objc func scrollP() {
    // -20 for status bar height
    if (self.scrollView.contentOffset.y - 20) > self.scrollView.frame.height * CGFloat(numPics + 1) {
        y = 0
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), animated: false)
    } else {
        y += 15
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: y), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Basically the concept is showing the first image and secretly(without animation) scroll back to the first image.

*Also, try not to initialize a large amount of views like UIImageView. Try to reuse the view and change the image associated to it.

Comment: sorry for delay I used your method But I have two questions :
1- why this scroll view will show white screen after scroll image ?
2- how can I Duplicate my image by appending to the end of the array ?
you mean my for loop is wrong ?

Comment: 1) The scroll view is showing white screen because there is no more view at the particular offset and the scroll view won't automatically goes back to 0 offset.
2) Duplicating the image and appending to the end of the array is simply used to create the illusion that the scroll view is scrolling infinitely. E.g. var images = [img1, img2, img1]. Your for loop is looping from 0...numPics which means 0 to 1 inclusive. It will run 2 times (0 and 1). FYI, ... means including the end index while ..< excludes it.

Comment: so you mean I should use array instead of for loop ?